# JQuery Using Cell Data to Reform Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery, as well as the CSVtoTable (plugin here: https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/ ) plugin to convert large CSV files into tables that I can manipulate. I need to attach links relevant to each row.

I need to convert the text in one of these rows to add a link to a pdf. The problem is I can't seem to modify the strings. I'm using data like that found here: http://jsfiddle.net/bstrunk/vaCuY/297/

The file names generated by my system can't be easily edited, so I'm stuck using these formats:

- 423-1.pdf

So I need to convert two strings from tables formatted like so:

- 4/23/2013
- 1

to drop the year, as well as the slashes, and add a '-' and then the extra digit. 
I'm able to grab the table data, I just can't seem to manipulate the variables with either the .replace or .substr

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function () {
        var $docket = $('td=eq(5)');
        var $td = $(this);
        var $dataDate = $td.substr(0, $td.lastIndexOf("/"));
        var $newDataDate = $dataDate.replace("/", "");
        $td.html('<a html="./docs/' + $newDataDate.text() + '-' + $docket.text() + '.pdf">' + $td.text() + '</a>');
    });
});
```

(edit): Sample table data:

```
<tr><td>13CI401111</td><td>22</td><td>Name1</td><td>Name2</td><td>4/23/2013</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>13CI401112</td><td>22</td><td>Name1</td><td>Name2</td><td>4/24/2013</td><td>2</td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample table row's HTML please?

Comment: Added sample table data above (Thanks for reading!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the table id properly:

```
<table id="CSVTable">
```

Then use the right selector to select the 5th cell in each row:

```
$("#CSVTable tr td:nth-child(5)") //note that we need to tell Jquery to look for the cells inside `CSVTable` otherwise it will search the whole document
```

dollar sign is not required at the beginning of each variable and doesn't have any significance, you can remove it.
This wont work:

```
var $docket = $('td=eq(5)');
```

it's telling jquery to look for 6th cell but where? you should specify the parent like:

```
$("#CSVTable tr td:nth-child(6)");
```

but we only need the next cell to the one already selected in `each` function, so a better approach would be to use `next()` method which will select the next td directly:

```
$(this).next('td');
```

complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CSVTable tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function () {
        var td = $(this),
            docket = td.next('td').text(),
            dataDate = td.text(),
            newDate = dataDate.substr(0, dataDate.lastIndexOf('/')).replace("/", '');

        td.html('<a href="/docs/' + newDate + '-' + docket + '.pdf">' + dataDate + '</a>');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/UPELM/)

Comment: Thank you, particularly for the detailed explanation. I'm just picking up the JQuery, and I obviously need to spend a bit more time studying. Thanks for the working code and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Bstrunk, try this :

```
$(function() {
    $("tr").each(function () {
        var $tr = $(this);
        var $td_date = $tr.find('td').eq(4);
        var $td_docket = $tr.find('td').eq(5);
        var dateArr = $td_date.text().split("/");
        $td_date.html('<a html="./docs/' + dateArr[0] + dateArr[1] + '-' + $td_docket.text() + '.pdf">' + $td_date.text() + '</a>');
    });
});
```